# Excel VBA get column as letter

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to get just the active column as a text to return in a message box?

I have this macro that shows a confirmation box,

```
Dim mycell
mycell = ActiveCell.Address

    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to trim column " & mycell & "?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

`code`
```

However I want to it ask "Are you sure you want to trim column F" for example, at the moment it will return the cell in the format $F$1. Can I get just the column name?

Comment: Just column name A, B, C..AA, BB etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to trim column " & Split(mycell, "$")(1) & "?", vbYesNo)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to the solution given by @Rory is replacing `Split(mycell, "$")(1)` by `Mid(mycell, 2, 1)`.

```
If ActiveCell.Column > 26 Then
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to trim column " & Mid(mycell, 2, 2) & "?", vbYesNo)
Else
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to trim column " & Mid(mycell, 2, 1) & "?", vbYesNo)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, can I ask if there is any benefit to either option or just simply an alternative?

Comment: There may be some scenarios where one of them could be preferred over the other. [This](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-substring-function/) page gives a nice explanation on the same. Also, I am updating my answer as per your latest comment. The previous one is only applicable for A-Z columns.

Comment: Now it won't work for columns AAA and across. ;) It's much simpler to use `Split`...

Comment: @Rory: I agree with you. Like I said in my answer it just an alternative and in this scenario it has a few limitations. :)